# Android ListView: Custom ListItem not displayed correctly

Tags: android, listview

based on an example i tried to create a ListView that displays custom ListItems.  I define the ListItem in XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I created a class to hold the data shown in a ListItem:

```
public class UserRecord {
    public String username;
    public String email;

    public UserRecord(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

I also have a custom ArrayAdapter:

```
public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserRecord> {
    private ArrayList<UserRecord> users;
    public LayoutInflater vi;
    private Context context;

    public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<UserRecord> users) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, users);
        this.users = users;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        }

        UserRecord user = users.get(position);
        if (user != null) {
            TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            TextView email = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);

            Log.v(TAG, "user " + user.username);
            Log.v(TAG, "mail " + user.email);
            if (username != null) {
                Log.v(TAG, "username NOT null");
                username.setText("user " + user.username);
            }

            if (email != null) {
                Log.v(TAG, "email NOT null");
                email.setText("Email: " + user.email);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Initialisation:

```
ArrayList<UserRecord> appointment;
UserItemAdapter aa;
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);

    appointment = new ArrayList<UserRecord>();
    aa = new UserItemAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, appointment);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);

}
```

And finally, when i push a button:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == b1) {
        UserRecord ur = new UserRecord("User " + i, "mail@mail.net");
        Log.v(TAG, "button 1 " + i);
        aa.add(ur);
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "unknown");
    }
}
```

Problem is that "email" is displayed, but "username" not, though it is handled the same way, i see no difference.  Also, the if() where it should be set is taken.

Has anybody got a hint on what is wrong?

Best regards
Torsten

Comment: Try removing the reference to your users Array (private ArrayList<UserRecord> users;) in your adapter. Instead, use getItem(position) to retrieve your items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
aa = new UserItemAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, appointment);
```

To this;

```
aa = new UserItemAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, appointment);
```

And try this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == b1) {
        UserRecord ur = new UserRecord("User " + i, "mail@mail.net");
        Log.v(TAG, "button 1 " + i);
        appointment.add(ur);
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "unknown");
    }
}
```

Comment: I took over your first part, but also this did not influence the behaviour, i think i need to read more about that.  Also, i don't think the notification is necessary, the items are added without problems, just the username was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but I am almost sure you should be doing this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == b1) {
        UserRecord ur = new UserRecord("User " + i, "mail@mail.net");
        Log.v(TAG, "button 1 " + i);
        users.add(ur);
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "unknown");
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == b1) {
        UserRecord ur = new UserRecord("User " + i, "mail@mail.net");
        Log.v(TAG, "button 1 " + i);
        aa.add(ur);
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "unknown");
    }
}
```

I have never added an item to my ADAPTER class, but always to the LIST of objects. In this case "users" rather than "aa".

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I also could be mistaken, but in the example it was described that the adapter could also be used for that.  Also, i don't miss entries in the list, if i add an item that works fine, just the username was missing (that itself is no sign that the code is ok).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your listitem.xml file. Try to change to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:text="Description"
    android:layout_below="@id/firstLine"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```